# Javascript ¿Cómo encerrar img dentro de elemento a?

Tags: javascript, html

Buenos días a toda la comunidad.

Tengo una función en `Javascript` que lee datos desde `JSON` y me trae unas imágenes. Estas imágenes las estoy mostrando en una página `HTML`. Hasta ahora ningún problema; lo que no estoy logrando es encerrar estas imágenes dentro de un elemento `<a>` ya que quiero que tengan un link.

Este es mi código JS.

```
<script>
    var jsonData2 = '[{"idc":"8","ima":"exis.png","title":"EXIS","especialidades":"-1-2-3-4-5-6-9-10-11-12-13-14-16-17-18-19-20-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-34-35-36-"}]'

    $(document).ready(function()
{
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonData2);
  var rowImg = document.getElementById("rowImg");

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    var object = data[i];
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/" + object.ima;
    img.id = object.idc;
    img.class = "img-responsive";
    img.title = object.title;
    img.style = "width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto";
    img.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object.ima));
    rowImg.appendChild(img);
    }
});
</script>
```

Así es como queda en el HTML:

```
  <div class="row" id="rowImg">
    <img src="images/exis.png" id="8" title="EXIS" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 0px auto;"></img>
  </div>
```

Esto es lo que estoy tratando de lograr:

```
  <div class="row" id="rowImg">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/exis.png" id="8" title="EXIS" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 0px auto;"></img></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No tienes más que crear un elemento link (`a`) igual que creas el de la imagen.

Añades la imagen como hijo del elemento link y es el link el que insertas en el DOM:

```js
    var jsonData2 = '[{"idc":"8","ima":"exis.png","title":"EXIS","especialidades":"-1-2-3-4-5-6-9-10-11-12-13-14-16-17-18-19-20-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-34-35-36-"}]'

$(document).ready(function()
{
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonData2);
  var rowImg = document.getElementById("rowImg");

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    var object = data[i];
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = "#";
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/" + object.ima;
    img.id = object.idc;
    img.class = "img-responsive";
    img.title = object.title;
    img.style = "width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto";
    img.appendChild(document.createTextNode(object.ima));
    link.appendChild(img);
    rowImg.appendChild(link);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rowImg"></div>
```

Comment: Genial. Realmente no me salía. Muchas gracias.